# Apache Subpath Wildcard Rewrite

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to set Apache up so that when I visit `https://example.com/v/{{ param }}` it (reverse?) proxies the request to `https://{{ param }}.example.com/v`.

I am also trying to wildcard `/v/*` so that it always proxies the request to the subdomain; it's a headless app whose URL structure I want to maintain. An example would be the URL in the browser being `https://example.com/v/param1/param2` but showing `https://param1.example.com/v`. You can talk to me on an intermediate level. I have tried `ProxyPass`, `ProxyPassMatch`, `ProxyPassRedirect`, all in .htaccess but I keep getting a 500 error.

Comment: Show exactly what you have already tried and the corresponding Apache error logs.